# Override global eslint config rules in subdirectory

Tags: configuration, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I'm migrating from **tslint** to **eslint**. However I'm unable to apply the rules in a similar way. A `.eslintrc.json` in a subdirectory is just ignored. But I need to override some rules for some subdirectories. In this case, the selector prefix should be `ui` instead `app` for all files in this subdirectory.

**Root** `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
   "root": true,
   "ignorePatterns": ["projects/**/*"],
   "overrides": [
      {
         "files": ["*.ts"],
         "parserOptions": {
            "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
            "createDefaultProgram": true
         },
         "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended", "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"],
         "rules": {
            "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "attribute",
                  "prefix": "app",
                  "style": "camelCase"
               }
            ],
            "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "element",
                  "prefix": "app",
                  "style": "kebab-case"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "files": ["*.html"],
         "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
         "rules": {}
      }
   ]
}
```

**src/elements/**`.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
   "overrides": [
      {
         "files": ["*.ts"],
         "rules": {
            "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "attribute",
                  "prefix": "ui",
                  "style": "camelCase"
               }
            ],
            "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "element",
                  "prefix": "ui",
                  "style": "kebab-case"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I had to add the `tsconfig.json` path in **parserOptions**. So the overriding file looks like this:

```json
{
   "overrides": [
      {
         "files": ["*.ts"],
         "parserOptions": {
            "project": ["../../../tsconfig.json"],
            "createDefaultProgram": true
         },
         "rules": {
            "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "attribute",
                  "prefix": "ui",
                  "style": "camelCase"
               }
            ],
            "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
               "error",
               {
                  "type": "element",
                  "prefix": "ui",
                  "style": "kebab-case"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```